# Поиск существующей записи Sql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

как, используя MySqlConnector для C#, отправить запрос к удаленной базе данных для проверки на существование записи?

```
sqlQuery = $"SELECT position FROM Positions WHERE barcode = {database[0, i]}";
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                    string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Здесь пытаюсь проверить на существование записи по штрих коду, и в случае, если записи нет, возникает исключение nullreferenceException в `string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`

Может есть другая команда или какое то свойство `MySqlCommand`, к которому можно обратиться при возврате результата запроса

Нашел в команду EXIST но в рамках phpMyAdmin ее не существует

Comment: Есть вариант - обработать исключение и "если оно появляется, то записи не существует" и в catch писать что делать в таком случае, но насколько я знаю, логика на исключениях - это плохо

Comment: `select count(*) where ...` — вернёт количество строк, удовлетворяющих условию. если ни одна не удовлетворяет — вернёт ноль. [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25e1a/14)

Comment: Использовать `COUNT` просто для проверки наличия записи это не оптимально для этого есть `EXISTS` но и в этом случае будет два запроса вместо одного, метод `ExecuteScalar` возвращает `Object` и не является безопасным, то есть он вернет `null` если записей нет. Что вам мешает проверить это прежде чем вызывать `ToString()`?